# Dojo Tooltip display always

Tags: charts, dojo, tooltip

Is it possible to make a tooltip display always in a chart?
I know that is possible to make it appears on mouse over using

```
new Tooltip(chart,"default");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `dijit/Tooltip` is it is build around [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), so you cannot display more than one tooltip at once.

Have a look at [Dojo Bootstrap](http://dojobootstrap.com/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/xsokev/Dojo-Bootstrap)) i.e. *Twitter Bootstrap for Dojo* and its [`Tooltip`](http://dojobootstrap.com/tooltip) or [`Popover`](http://dojobootstrap.com/popover). They are solid alternatives.